# Enter value into cells and not paste from clipboard

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel macro (main file) that will open another workbook (data source) and is supposed to paste the data from some rows to the current workbook (main file).

There is something wrong that the macro pastes what I copied (stored in the clipboard I think) in the cell that I selected before I press Button1. I tried clearing the clipboard but it was useless.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Button1_Click()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim last_row, i, j As Long
Dim wo_num As String

'open data source

Dim data_source As Workbook
Dim destination As Workbook

Set destination = ThisWorkbook
Set data_source = Workbooks.Open("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", True, True)
Application.DisplayAlerts = False


'refresh data source connection to database
'data_source.RefreshAll

last_row = data_source.Worksheets(3).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

wo_num = "0000057305"
j = 1

'search for the cell that match wo_num and copy entire row then paste on main file
For i = 2 To last_row
    If data_source.Worksheets(3).Cells(i, 1) = wo_num Then
        'data_source.Worksheets(3).Rows(i).EntireRow.Copy
        destination.Worksheets(1).Rows(j).Value = data_source.Worksheets(3).Rows(i).Value
        destination.Worksheets(1).Paste
        j = j + 1
    End If
Next i

data_source.Close False

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

'clear the clipboard
Application.CutCopyMode = False

MsgBox "Done!"

End Sub
```

What happened on my screen
[image: What happened on my screen]

The cell contains "destination.Worksheets(1).Cells(1, 26).Select" is the line of code I have just press Ctrl+C.

Comment: Your code does not contain that line of code.

Comment: Yes, GMalc, I removed that line. My idea was to manually select an empty cell and clear it but no use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using array based of copying data, no need to use `paste` as you are not copying anything to clipboard. 
Just simply remove this line or make it as a comment by adding `'` or `REM` to the first of that line, exactly like what you did for entirerow.copy line ;-)  .

```
 For i = 2 To last_row
    If data_source.Worksheets(3).Cells(i, 1) = wo_num Then
        'data_source.Worksheets(3).Rows(i).EntireRow.Copy
        destination.Worksheets(1).Rows(j).Value = data_source.Worksheets(3).Rows(i).Value
        ' destination.Worksheets(1).Paste !! run your code without this line and see what is happening. 
        j = j + 1
    End If
Next i
```

Hope this fix your issue. Otherwise, we need to know when something is copied into the clipboard. 
Another comment could be not transfering all the row, if you dont really have value in all 16384 columns of a sheet. Use `cells(i,1).resize(,numberof columns)` to make your code more agile.

```
      destination.Worksheets(1).cells(j,1).resize(,NumberofColumns).Value = data_source.Worksheets(3).cells(i,1).resize(,NumberofColumns).Value
```

good job anyway,

Regards,
M

Comment: Thank so much, Mahhdy. You save me a day. By the way, your advise is also great!